# PHP file called by javascript and another php file

Tags: javascript, php

I have a php file (I will call ORIGINAL) which do some calculations (through db mysql). I want to read this php from javascript. For that operation I have used ajax function and my php uses echo $result to print the data I need.

Everything is perfect here.

What happends now, I am creating another php file which need to call the ORIGINAL php file. If I want to call it, I must change the echo to return which is normal. This causes that my javascript call doesnt work.

Do you have a solution which work for both situations?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a conditional and return different content for each call. Start with `if(!empty($_POST['ajax'])) { do ajax stuff exit(); }` and have your ajax send `ajax` with a value as well.

Comment: Use different files for these calls, extract common functionality into another one and include it in both.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

***original_php_file.php***:

```
<?php 
    require_once "other_php_file.php"; // include all of the other files contents

    // all code contained within original_php_file
?>
```

You were being pretty broad with your request (not including file names or code), so this is all I can assume you need.

Tell me if it helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just send one more parameter into your ajax request to tell that ORIGINAL php file what type of output it should return.

Into your ORIGINAL file check for that output so you can understand from where that request come and what output you should return.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'ORIGINAL.php',
    data: 'data=test&output=1',
    success: function(r){
        // here you have your output
    }
});
```